# Building Species distribution modells for species within a raster stack

Tags: r, raster, glm, terra, maxent

I have run a GLM Species Distribution Model for a single species, but I want to replicate this for a different species within a raster stack. I initially ran an SDM for one species and got an error trying to run this model on the raster stack consisting of other species. I want a function that gets a raster stack of predicted presence probabilities in the raster stack and returns a stack of predicted presence/absence for each species.

This is what I have tried:

````r
Occurrence_data1 <- data.frame(
  lon = c(11.002470, 10.733250, 11.135831, 6.003845, 5.073000, 8.859500, 10.740000),
  lat = c(59.05563, 63.57087, 60.15113, 62.40066, 60.11600, 58.62880, 59.95000),
  species = c("B.terrestris", "B.pascuorum", "B.hortorum", "B.pratorum", "B.terrestris", "B.pascuorum", "B.hortorum")
) 

# filter out dataframe for single species 
Occurrence_data <- B_occurrences1|>
  dplyr::arrange(species)%>%
  group_by(species) %>%
  distinct(latitude, longitude, .keep_all = TRUE)%>% # to work on just one species run the next code 
  filter(species == "B. terrestris sensu lato")

#create paths 
dir.create(path = "data")
dir.create(path = "output")

#Load libraries 
pacman::p_load(terra, geodata, predicts) 

##download climate data 
bioclim_data <-geodata::worldclim_country("Norway",  path= "data/", var="bio", res =0.5) #download=T

#plot(bioclim_data[[1]])
#plot(Occurrence_data$longitude, Occurrence_data$latitude)
#Before we do any modeling, it is also a good idea to run a reality check on your occurrence data
# Download data with geodata's world function to use for our base map
world_map <- world(resolution =2.5,
                   path = "data/")

# Crop the map to our area of interest
my_map <- crop(x = world_map, y = geographic_extent)

#####prepare data for modelling
# Make an extent that is 25% larger
sample_extent <- geographic_extent * 1.25

# Crop bioclim data to desired extent
bioclim_data <- crop(x = bioclim_data, y = sample_extent)

# Plot the first of the bioclim variables to check on cropping
plot(bioclim_data[[1]])

#The pseudo-absence point or “background” points.
# Set the seed for the random-number generator to ensure results are similar
set.seed(20210707)
# Randomly sample points (same number as our observed points)
background <- spatSample(x = bioclim_data,
                         size = 10000,    # generate 10,000 pseudo-absence points
                         values = FALSE, # don't need values
                         na.rm = TRUE,   # don't sample from ocean
                         xy = TRUE)      # just need coordinates

#We have observation data and pseudo-absence data and we need to first put them into one data structure, 
#then add in the climate data so we have a single data frame with presence points and pseudo-absence points, and climate data for each of these points
# Pull out coordinate columns, x (longitude) first, then y (latitude) from 
# Bombus model data 
presence <- Occurrence_data[, c("longitude", "latitude")]
# Add column indicating presence
presence$pa <- 1

# Convert background data to a data frame
absence <- as.data.frame(background)
# Update column names so they match presence points
colnames(absence) <- c("longitude", "latitude")
# Add column indicating absence
absence$pa <- 0

# Join data into single data frame
all_points <- rbind(presence, absence)

###Add climate data
#add climate data to the coordinate data sets
bioclim_extract <- terra::extract(x = bioclim_data,
                           y = all_points[, c("longitude", "latitude")],
                           ID = FALSE) # No need for an ID column

#we need to join these extracted data back with our all_points data frame. After we do this, we do not need the latitude and longitude coordinates anymore, 
#so we can drop those two columns (at least for building the model). Add the point and climate datasets together
points_climate <- cbind(all_points, bioclim_extract)

# Identify columns that are latitude & longitude
drop_cols <- which(colnames(points_climate) %in% c("longitude", "latitude"))
drop_cols # print the values as a reality check
# Remove the geographic coordinates from the data frame
points_climate <- points_climate[, -drop_cols]

##I create a raster that has all the conditions equal to study Area
## and then use the values of the cells without NAs (cells with NA are the ocean)
## to remove NAs from points_climate 
points_climate <- na.omit(points_climate)

##Training and testing data
#We are going to reserve 20% of the data for testing and to evenly assign each point to a random group (Test /Train) using function from the predicts package
# Create vector indicating fold
fold <- folds(x = points_climate,
              k = 5,
              by = points_climate$pa)# use the pa column to create the folds 
table(fold)

#We will say that any observations in fold 1 will be testing data, and any observations in the other folds (2, 3, 4, 5) will be training data
testing <- points_climate[fold == 1, ]
training <- points_climate[fold != 1, ]

####Model Building
## Build a model using training data
glm_model <- glm(pa ~ ., data = training, family = binomial())

# Get predicted values from the model
glm_predict <- predict(bioclim_data, glm_model, type = "response")

# Print predicted values
plot(glm_predict)
 
#We now take that model, and evaluate it using the observation data and the pseudo-absence points we reserved for model testing. 
#We then use this test to establish a cutoff of occurrence probability to determine the boundaries of the Bombus  range.
# Use testing data for model evaluation
glm_eval <- pa_evaluate(p = testing[testing$pa == 1, ],
                        a = testing[testing$pa == 0, ],
                        model = glm_model,
                        type = "response")

# Determine minimum threshold for "presence"
glm_threshold <- glm_eval@thresholds$max_spec_sens

#And finally, we can use that threshold to paint a map with sites predicted to be suitable for the Bombus species
# Plot base map
plot(my_map, 
     axes = TRUE, 
     col = "grey95")

# Only plot areas where probability of occurrence is greater than the threshold
plot(glm_predict > glm_threshold, 
     add = TRUE, 
     legend = FALSE, 
     col = c(NA, "olivedrab")) # <-- Update the values HERE

# And add those observations
points(x = Occurrence_data$longitude, 
       y = Occurrence_data$latitude, 
       col = "black",
       pch = "+", 
       cex = 0.75)

# Redraw those country borders
plot(my_map, add = TRUE, border = "grey5")

#create a raster stack 
species_list <- unique(Occurrence_data1$species)

v <- terra::vect(Occurrence_data1)
r <- terra::rast(nrows = 12, ncols = 12, crs = "EPSG:4326", ext = terra::ext(v))
#And let's rasterize the points:
x <- terra::rasterize(v, r, fun = "count", by = "species")
names(Bombus_rasterstack) <- species_list

# Convert SpatRaster to a raster stack
Bombus_rasterstack-> Bombus_rasterstack %>% stack()
names(x) <- species_list ```
````

Comment: Please update your answer to include a copy of B_occurrences1. Or is B_occurrences1 is actually supposed to be Occurrence_data1? Also include all the libraries required to run your code. You have also used a mix of pipes which is generally bad practice. Further, this isn't a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121) as there is a lot of code here that doesn't need to be. Please strip the code back to just the essential parts required to answer your question. Implementing these suggestions will increase your chances of getting an answer.